# Get a file into an S3 bucket in every region

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a .zip file (in an S3 bucket) that needs to end up in an S3 bucket in every region within a single account.

Each of those buckets have identical bucket policies that allow for my account to upload files to them, and they all follow the same naming convention, like this:
foobar-{region}

ex: foobar-us-west-2

Is there a way to do this without manually dragging the file in the console into every bucket, or using the aws s3api copy-object command 19 times?  This may need to happen fairly frequently as the file is updated, so I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it.

One way I thought about doing it was by making a lambda that has an array of all 19 regions I need, then loop through them to create 19 region-specific bucket names, each of which will have the object copied into it.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply putting it into bash function. By using aws cli and jq you can do the following;

```
    aws s3api list-buckets | jq -rc .Buckets[].Name | while read i; do 
      echo "Bucket name: ${i}"
      aws s3 cp your_file_name s3://${i}/
    done
```

Comment: this might work, but unfortunately I'm in a position where I can't require that people install the jq command so they can use this script

Comment: if install jq is too much then your can always use --query option which is part of the aws cli. See some examples in -> [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Comment: For example `aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"` but you may have to ignore first and the list item as they will be square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- An **AWS Lambda function** could be triggered upon upload. It could then confirm whether the object *should* be replicated (eg I presume you don't want to copy *every* file that is uploaded?), then copy them out. Note that it can take quite a while to copy to all regions.
- Use **Cross-Region Replication** to copy the contents of a bucket (or sub-path) to other buckets. This would be done automatically upon upload.
- Write a bash script or small Python program to run locally that will **copy the file to each location**. Note that it is more efficient to call `copy_object()` to copy the file from one S3 bucket to another rather than uploading 19 times. Just upload to the first bucket, then copy from there to the other locations.

Comment: cross-region replication would have been perfect, but apparently it only supports replication to a single other bucket - I need to replicate to multiple other buckets

Comment: I think you can chain the buckets: A -> B -> C